Histoire not working with custom Vue component
I am trying to integrate Histoire in my Vue project (with Vite) and I successfully integrated it by creating a new component. But when I try to integrate it with an existing component of mine that gets some data from an api, it keeps giving me this import error
How can I fix this?
[vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "~/src/core-asset-studio/assetsSupport" from "components/asset-studio/DistributionRoomCard.vue". Does the file exist?
Error while collecting story /workspace/{projectName}/components/asset-studio/DistributionRoomCard.story.vue:
Error: Failed to resolve import "~/src/assetsSupport" from "components/asset-studio/DistributionRoomCard.vue". Does the file exist?

